# OpenLayersPlugin doesn't not load anything

Tags: qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have some issues with the OpenLayers Plugin. I have already installed the plugin, though when i choose to add for example the google hybrid layer or anything else it doesn't do anything, just that it tries to load something.What should i do? 
thanks.[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you try reloading QGIS and then selecting an open layer?

Comment: I already have an open layer and then i try to add the google hybrid layer and it just loads ![Valid XHTML](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t35.0-12/10503331_10203531572983353_911459542_o.jpg?oh=3d7e696c0f4d7839c5ffd7ac1450d340&oe=53BCBC04&__gda__=1404876437_14711e91b5981fedab072f4a7d56683b).

Comment: Try reinstalling the plugin. Quit QGIS and start it up again. From your image, check if the 'Points' layer is also set to EPSG:3857? If it still doesn't work then disable/enable the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

First load a vetor layer of the area of your interest, then activate `On-the-fly-reprojection` and set the **project** CRS to EPSG:3857. The vector layer can have any other **layer** CRS.

If you still see nothing, you might be trapped behind some proxy.

---

**EDIT**

There is a brand new release of the plugin, which should now support QGIS 2.4 too:
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/openlayers_plugin/version/1.3.3/